# How to make React and Redux template as small as possible after npm install?

Tags: reactjs, npm, redux

The template being considered is https://github.com/StephenGrider/ReduxSimpleStarter

After `git clone`, the folder is merely 160kb.

But after `npm install`, the folder is 620MB.

Is there a way to make it as small as possible?  It was suspected that the react native stuff (including the binaries?) is really huge, so can something be done such as `npm install --minus react-native` if react native is not needed at all?

**P.S.** a few days have passed, and today Apr 2, 2017, the same repo, the same as before, after `npm install`, is only 138MB. I guess somebody fixed the dependencies (of the npm modules registry), so that some 500MB of stuff is not installed.

Comment: Why do you think it installed react-native? It's not in the package.json, and doesn't seem to be a react-native project.

Comment: I asked a quick question to the repo owner, and he said could it be due to react native

Answer (score 0):

There is no `react-native` in the starter project that you referenced. :)
So, that is not what is causing the large directory.

It is typical to have a large `node_modules` directory.  This directory is usually placed in the `.gitignore` (or similar) so that it is *not* committed to the source control repository.

In order to track dependencies, use the `--save` and `--save-dev` switches in `npm install` and make sure to commit your `package.json`

Also, when you `npm install` for production, use the `npm install --production` switch to exclude dev dependencies.

Comment: I still remember buying a hard drive that was 1GB and was thinking whether to get the 2GB and the salesperson asked me "are you sure you really need 2GB?" Even nowadays, if the notebook's SSD is 128GB, then a few of these repo will be 5GB, and it is a problem if the hard drive available space was a few GB

Comment: Yes, 2GB hardrive was **luxury** :)  For node projects, if you save your dependencies, you can always delete the `node_modules` directory to temporarily save space.

Answer (score 0):

When you run npm install all dependencies will be installed as from package.json, 
this includes devDependencies and dependencies (using npm you can also control what to install or not as Davin Tryon pointed out). Below an extract from your package.json you can see all dep included. Also you could consider ignoring `node_modules` on git or svn to do use space on your repository.

You could consider manually remove the `node_modules` directory if you do not work on a project so you can save some space on you HD.

```
 "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.2.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.1.18",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.1.18",
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "chai-jquery": "^2.0.0",
    "jquery": "^2.2.1",
    "jsdom": "^8.1.0",
    "mocha": "^2.4.5",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^0.14.7",
    "webpack": "^1.12.9",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-preset-stage-1": "^6.1.18",
    "lodash": "^3.10.1",
    "react": "^0.14.3",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.3",
    "react-redux": "^4.0.0",
    "react-router": "^2.0.1",
    "redux": "^3.0.4"
  }
```

Comment: There is no way to make a React / Redux project with node modules that are merely 10, 20MB?  620MB seems like huge... it is like it has its own copy of Microsoft Visual Studio of the old days...

Comment: @太極者無極而生 I understand how you feel, and to be honest as fair I know there is no way to reduce the size apart do not include dependencies which are not being used actually in your project.